# C implementation of PulseEvent() function

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, events

I need to write a C code implementation of the PulseEvent for a manual-reset event. So, this function, has to released all the waiting threads and, after that, the event is reset.
I can only use semaphore and mutexes with their windows function (CreateSemaphore, CreateMutex, ReleaseSemaphore, ReleaseMutex)
I have to do this for an university exam so I don't have any support information for you.

Comment: You should note that, if you want to accurately simulate the functionality of Windows MRE, you should understand that it is borken.  If an MRE is set and quickly reset while there are multiple threads waiting on it, only those threads that actually get to run before the reset will run on after it.  Any remainder will be set back to blocked on the MRE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that an approximate simulation would be to have all threads enter a mutex. If a thread enters with a wait request, create a semaphore, store it in a container, exit the mutex and wait on the semaphore.

If the thread enters the mutex with a pulse request, signal all the semaphores in the container, empty the container, (no, do not CloseHandle the semaphores), and exit the mutex.

The released threads should CloseHandle the semaphore they were waiting on before running on further.